# 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx

I'm trying to move my root directory from /var/www/html to ~/website for easy access and looser permissions.

Here's /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 with IPs omitted (the original error.log lists an error that has since been fixed):

```
2019/08/19 12:26:19 [error] 16659#16659: *90 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: omitted, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "omitted"
2019/08/19 21:41:00 [error] 16659#16659: *116 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: omitted, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "omitted"
```

I only have a simple index.html in the ~/website directory for testing purposes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>It worked!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Did it?</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Research has told me that if there's no issue with the files themselves, there's something wrong with the config file. Here's /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
https://hastebin.com/uquqijiyex.nginx

`grep "root" -R /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` will return the following:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:       root ~/website;
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:       # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:#      root /var/www/example.com;
```

And here's the contents of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
https://hastebin.com/iputohokuh.nginx

`sudo nginx -t` returns with no errors, and I have restarted Nginx.

Please let me know if I've missed any information, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use relative paths in your docroot settings.  Use full paths.  `/home/USERNAME/website` for example.